# How can I filter elements in two lists with C# and .NET 6?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have 2 lists like this, what I want to do is to take the non-identical values in these 2 lists into a third list, how can I do this with C#?

```
List<int> listOne = new List<int>() { 112, 113, 114 };
List<int> listTwo = new List<int>() { 112, 113, 114, 115, 116 };

List<int> filteredList = new List<int>();
```

Exactly what I want to do is to pass the unmatched values in `listOne` and `listTwo` into `filteredList`. So `115` and `116` values need to be passed into the `filteredList`. How can I do this?

Comment: What should we do with *duplcates*? E.g. what is the expected result for `listOne = {1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3}` and `listTwo = {2, 2, 3, 3, 4}`?

Comment: Maybe rewrite with Sets and use Except? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/set-operations#except-and-exceptby

Comment: `list2.Except(list1)`?

Comment: You have asked 12 questions in 2 months. Can you try searching before asking a new one, and show what you have tried?

Comment: @Sasha: it depends on what should we do with duplicates. If we don't have any or if we should operate with distinct values, then sets can be a solution.

Comment: The expected result for this list is that there are only `4` in the `filteredList`.

Comment: @imuzz01: since you don't want values in `listOne` and you want *distinct* values only, then use *Fildor's* solution: `filteredList = listTwo.Except(listOne).ToList();`

Comment: Is it possible that list1 contains more items than list2 and then you want those? What about "1, 2, 3" and "1, 2, 4" - would then "3,4" be expected?

Comment: Yes, these lists will come as variables and may contain different items from each other. When I use Except, we filter from the list with excess items, but in the opposite case, this code does not work, it returns me an empty list. @Fildor

Comment: Then it will be a little more complex. Like maybe `list1.Except(list2).union(list2.Except(list1))` or something similar. At which point it may be worthwhile to think about a non- linq solution.

Answer (score 0):

Scanning for duplicates is a very costly operation, something like O(n^2) which is extremely bad. As such you would want to employ a HashSet for this which would reduce the time complexity to something close to O(n) which is far better:-

```
            List<int> listOne = new List<int>() { 112, 113, 114 };
            List<int> listTwo = new List<int>() { 112, 113, 114, 115, 116 };

            //Create a HashSet with the values from the bigger list
            var filteredList = new HashSet<int>(listTwo);

            //Remove items from the HashSet that also exist in the smaller list
            filteredList.ExceptWith(listOne);

            // Print the filtered list to the immediate window
            foreach (var i in filteredList) Debug.WriteLine(i.ToString());
```

The above code outputs this:-

```
115
116
```